# Changing the rich:simpleTogglePanel header style

Tags: java, css, jsf, richfaces

Is it possible to change the **header style** of a rich:simpleTogglePanel ?? The font of the header is always "bold" and I want it to be normal.

I tried with the style attribute this way: style="font-weight:normal" without result.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried putting the `!important` at the end of your style definition(i.e. `style="font-weight:normal !important;"`)?

Also, as I'm sure you are aware, it is usually better to specify your style in a separate stylesheet.  I've customized the `<rich:extendedDataTable` in this manner (not sure if this is a hack or not, but it works great for me).  Open your page in a browser and then crack open the developer tools (press F12 in Firefox with FireBug installed, or in Chrome right click on the `rich:SimpleTogglePanel` and click 'Inspect Element'.  This will let you see the CSS definition name used by the RichFaces framework.  Just create a new .css file and define the style you want using the name you find RichFaces is using.

```
/*This class defines styles for a table cell.*/  
/*tableBorderWidth, tableBorderColor    border-bottom*/  
/*tableBorderWidth, tableBorderColor    border-right*/  
.rf-edt-c {  
    border-bottom: 1px solid #021e2f;  
    border-right: 1px solid #021e2f;  
    height: auto !important;  
    min-height: 26px;  
}
```

As you can see, you may need to specify the `!important` tag there as well, but it keeps the style outside of your page...

Hope this helps.